# Writing URDF for robot

Tags: ros, urdf, github

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, am still new to ROS Noetic and the progress is not as smooth even while following ROS tutorial.
Going through tutorial for urdf, the explanation on how to write urdf is understandable but it does not state where we can write our urdf.xacro file.

I have tried to edit the urdf file from urdf_tutorial but was unable to edit it.

I have also tried cloning github files to try launching the urdf.xacro file but is faced with issues as well.
This is how i clone from github:

```
odroid@odroid:~$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
odroid@odroid:~/catkin_ws/src$ git clone https://github.com/bandasaikrishna/Autonomous_Mobile_Robot.git
odroid@odroid:~/catkin_ws/src$ cd ~/catkin_ws
odroid@odroid:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
odroid@odroid:~/catkin_ws$ . ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

But launching the file from the one I clone from github returns:

```
odroid@odroid:~/catkin_ws/src/mobile_robot_autonomous_navigation$ roslaunch check_urdf.launch model:=urdf/mobile_robot.urdf
RLException: [check_urdf.launch] is not a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Tried other solutions:

```
odroid@odroid:~$ source /home/odroid/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
odroid@odroid:~$ roslaunch mobile_robot_autonomous_navigation check_urdf.launch


RLException: Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: no such command [['/opt/ros/noetic/share/xacro/xacro.py', '/home/odroid/catkin_ws/src/mobile_robot_autonomous_navigation/urdf/mobile_robot.urdf.xacro']].

Param xml is <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(arg model)"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

So question in summary:
1- Where and how can I create and write urdf file?
2- What are the errors I have faced aboveand any soluiton?

I Thank you all in advance and really appreciate any help.
Thank you, really.

ANSWER:
The main issue is due to `xacro.py` being deprecated. Though my workspace does seem to have issue with sourcing the `setup.bash` from `catkin_ws`.
Deleted and re-build (used `catkin build` instead of `catkin_make`) Catkin workspace and ran `source /home/odroid/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396250/writing-urdf-for-robot/) by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2022-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the repo in your link was developed for an older ROS distro.

`xacro.py` is deprecated.

In `autonomous_nav.launch` file found [here](https://github.com/bandasaikrishna/Autonomous_Mobile_Robot/blob/main/mobile_robot_autonomous_navigation/launch/autonomous_nav.launch) replace the following:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(arg model)"/>
```

to:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(arg model)"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on 2022-02-16**:
Alright. Thank you for replying. Thought it was a possibility but failed to find it while reading through the files(thinking I will find other distro name like kinetic etc).

Will report back when I am back in the lab and try it out.

Also, if possible, regarding sourcing the setup.bash file in "catkin_ws/devel" using:

```
echo "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

is not working. Opening another terminal shows

```
home/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

Thanks again.